# Can't figure out the time complexity of function

Tags: python, time-complexity, computer-science

I wanted a function that, given a list of integers `num`, would return a list of the `k` most frequent elements in it. I wrote the following function

```
    def topKFrequent(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> List[int]:
        freqs = {} # num:freq
        # time complexity of this loop is O(N), where N is the size of nums
        # space complexity of this loop is O(N)

        for num in nums:
            if num in freqs:
                freqs[num] += 1
            else:
                freqs[num] = 1

        # this loop has the same time and space complexity as the previous one
        inverse_freqs = {} #freq:num
        for num in freqs.keys():
            if freqs[num] in inverse_freqs:
                inverse_freqs[freqs[num]].append(num)
            else:
                inverse_freqs[freqs[num]] = [num]

        sorted_freqs = list(inverse_freqs.keys())
        # this sort is the part which I don't understand
        sorted_freqs.sort()
        l = []
        i = 0
        #these 2 loops together are O(N)
        while len(l) < k:
            for most_freq_element in inverse_freqs[sorted_freqs[-i-1]]:
                l.append(most_freq_element)
            i += 1
        return l
```

Let's call the number of different frequencies `F`. The sorting is obviously `O(F * log F)`

The `sorted_freqs` list is biggest in proportion to `N` when `nums` is something like [1, 2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5....]. The question I have is how to figure out how `F` grows in proportion to `N`, and then calculate the time complexity from there.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you don't need `inverse_freqs` at all, just `return sorted(freqs, key=freqs.get, reverse=True)[:k]` (or, of course, `return collections.Counter(nums).most_common(k)`).

Comment: iirc in the worst case scenario N grows significantly faster than F, so sorting F will not change your time complexity. for example, for F to be of length 50, N will have to be at least 1275

Comment: @Nullman Good point, considering this, the entire algorithm would be just O(N) and thus faster than the (simpler) alternatives I've shown (not sure if `Counter` does something similar internally).

Comment: @Nullman I am under the exact same impression, just want to make sure I'm not getting anything wrong

Comment: I found a similar solution to mine: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YPTqKIgVk-k and it is O(N) indeed. I won't post an answer because I'll leave the accepted answer for someone who can give me a formula for `F` :)

Comment: Well, in the worst case, i.e. frequencies as 1, 2, 3, ..., F, you have F*(F+1)/2 = N different numbers, so F ~ sqrt(2N)?

Comment: Yes @tobias_k you are correct. If you post an answer I'll accept it

Comment: The key insight was from @Nullman though.

Answer (score -1):

When analyzing the function:

Constructing the freqs dictionary takes time based on the size of nums, which we'll call N. This is O(N).
Making the inverse_freqs dictionary also takes time up to O(N).

Sorting the sorted_freqs list takes time based on the number of unique frequencies, which we'll call F. This is O(FlogF).

In the worst case, when every number in nums is unique, F is the same as N, making it O(NlogN).

Building the final list l takes time up to O(N).
When you sum everything up, the most time-consuming part is the sorting, which is
O(NlogN) in the worst case.

Therefore, the overall time complexity is O(NlogN).

Comment: "In the worst case, when every number in nums is unique, F is the same as N" No, in this case, F will be 1.

Comment: Exactly @tobias_k

Comment: More precisely, the number of different frequencies can be the same as the number of different numbers, and the number of different numbers can be the same as the number of numbers, but the number of different frequencies can _not_ be the same as the number of numbers.